# Возможно ли возвращать другое значенние в doReturn().when() при следующей итерации. Java/Mockito

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, mockito

Постараюсь по простому объяснить, чего я хочу добиться.

Допустим есть такой цикл

```
public void aMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        System.out.println(mockedService.getList());
    }
}
```

Могу ли я с помощью констуркции `doReturn().when()` из теста сделать так, **чтобы при первой и второй итерации возвращались два разных листа, при этом не изменяя сам aMethod()?** Т.е. нужно что-то вроде такого:

```
doReturn(firstList).when(mockedService.getList()) // при первой итерации
doReturn(secondList).when(mockedService.getList()) // при второй итерации
```

Чтобы в консоль вывелось:

```
firstList
secondList
```

Как это можно реализовать, если getList() без параметров?

Comment: Можно если поставить if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сделай цепочку вызовов:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MockitoTest {

    interface Callback {

        String call();

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Callback mock = Mockito.mock(Callback.class);
        Mockito.doReturn("first").doReturn("second").when(mock).call();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            result.add(mock.call());
        }
        Assertions.assertEquals("first", result.get(0));
        Assertions.assertEquals("second", result.get(1));
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Callback mock = Mockito.mock(Callback.class);
        Mockito.when(mock.call()).thenReturn("first").thenReturn("second");
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            result.add(mock.call());
        }
        Assertions.assertEquals("first", result.get(0));
        Assertions.assertEquals("second", result.get(1));
    }
}
```

[Англ. версия](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785498/simulate-first-call-fails-second-call-succeeds)